# Как с помощью python синтезировать голос моего знакомого?

Tags: python, python-3.x, синтезатор-речи

Пишу умного голосового ассистента. Хочу заставить его говорить *голосом своего друга*. Ясное дело, что можно просто озвучить каждый звук русского алфавита по отдельности, а затем просто из этих звуков составлять слова, но этот способ мне не нравится из-за низкого качества результата. Слышал про *технологию DeepFake*. **Можно ли с ее помощью как-то решить проблему?**

Comment: Русский алфавит не состоит из звуков. А буквы иногда имеют разные звучания. Можете начитать мягкий знак. Лучше пусть начитает слова. Это от 30 слов до десятков тысяч.

Comment: Я знаю, что алфавит состоит не из звуков, просто немного неправильно выразился, извиняюсь:)

Comment: Просто я планирую ассистенту генеративную модель ответов, а не retrieval (вроде бы так называется, но я не уверен). То есть, у ассистента будет генерация ответов исходя из контекста вопроса, а не уже заготовленный ответ на заранее продуманный вопрос.

Comment: Поэтому мне нужно именно синтезировать голос друга, а не зачитать с десяток тысяч слов на диктофон.

Comment: А касательно мягких и твердых знаков - достаточно лишь записать сочетания всех согласных букв с каждым по отдельности.

Comment: Вам как минимум нужна фонетическая транскрипция слов. Для английского такое есть.

Comment: Я тоже о ней подумал, но меня сейчас интересует скорее плавность синтеза речи, чем правильность произносимых слов.

Comment: Для руського языка просто слова недостаточно. Пишем молоко, читаем мАлАко там вместо А могут быть разные звуки, в зависимости от того, как хорошо человек владеет диалектом. И таких примеров сотни.

Comment: Просто даже если произнести мОлОко, то человек все равно поймет о чем речь. Я понимаю, что при retrieval-модели ответов придется обратиться к фонетике, в отличие от нейронных сетей, как подсказали ниже.

Comment: я случайно нажал эту ужасную кнопку. не повторяйте моих ошибок, не жмите её!

Comment: да, человек поймет, но наверно Ваш друг говорит на порядок лучше

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это очень хороший вопрос!

Дело в том, что даже голоса тех ассистентов, которые "доступны публично", построены на основе голоса живого человека, конкретного диктора.

За счёт того, что обучение сети, синтезирующей голос ассистента, проводилось очень компетентными специалистами-модель получилась качественная, и была создана на основе не очень большой обучающей выборки.

Возможен другой путь - обучение сети с нуля, на основе только голоса конкретного человека. Но при этом возникает проблема: нужна а)большая и б) тщательно размещенная обучающая выборка

Что такое "размещенная выборка"? Это значит, что про любую фразу известен исходный текст, и некая "метаинформация", которую упрощённо можно назвать "интонационная окраска". К примеру, если Вы проспали и опаздываете, логично, что "помощник" сообщит Вам об этом взволнованно.

Ну вот, если такая размещенная выборка есть-то тренировка сети на ее основе-это уже технический и хорошо отработанный вопрос. Но вся трудность - именно в обучающей выборке.

Comment: Понял, то есть советуете изучить теорию по обучению нейронных сетей?

Comment: Ну, есть простой путь: есть такая книжка "искусственный интеллект на Python", и там есть примеры с обучением сетей. Кроме того, присмотритесь к проекту wosk

Comment: Спасибо вам большое)